# Jersey reuse parameter validation for subresources

Tags: java, api, rest, validation, jersey

I have to following endpoint structure in Jersey:

```
/objects/
/objects/:id
/objects/:id/:field
/objects/:id/:field/:subfield
```

The IDs I'm using have a very specific format, so I first check if the format is valid before making a request to the database.

Right now I have to put this code in each of the `POST`, `PUT`, `GET`, `DELETE` functions for each of the functions that has `:id` as a parameter. So this just means an early return.

```
if (!isIdValid(id)){
    return Response.status(Response.StatusType.BAD_REQUEST)
                   .entity("The ID you've provided is invalid")
                   .build();
}
```

(In reality the error entity is an object containing more information about the error)

And then for each function using the `:field` or `:subfield` parameters the code is similar. This checking and error-handling behavior has to be copied every time. And when I start copy-pasting stuff, I start thinking: there should be a better way?

I would like to place the `:id` checking code at the the `/objects/:id` level, and then all further nested levels are assumed have a valid ID. The same for the other parameters further nesting down.

I've been looking into using subresource locators, but then you create a function returning a new instance of the subresource. I can't put a conditional return of a `Response`-object at that level for if the validation fails.

```
@Path("{id}")
function Class<ObjectFieldResource> getObjectById(@PathParam("id") String id){
    return ObjectFieldResource.class;
}
```

I could start *throwing* exceptions, but I would rather avoid that, since I don't really consider invalid input to be an *exception*.

How would such a structure best be implemented? I've looked at bean validation but that doesn't seem to allow me to define validation for my specific format + custom error responses.

Am I missing something in the way subresources should be implemented?

Comment: I know you said you didn't like exception, but you could have a checkID method that throws an Exception and then use a mapper to transform that exception back into a Response with the relevant information. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6665

Comment: I currently have a generic exception mapper that does that. But I could indeed create separate exception classes for each kind of validation error. Could easily get out of hand though. But if that's the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

If you can use regexp checks instead of your `isIdValid` method it's possible to define your resources like this

```
@POST
@Path("objects/{id:\\d+}")
public Response doSmth(@PathParam("id") String id) {
...
}
```

In a case of invalid `id` format caller will have 'Not Found' response status without even reaching your `doSmth` method.

Obviously, you can use String constants for all equal path values.

```
final static String ID_RES = "objects/{id:\\d+}";

@POST
@Path(ID_RES)
public Response postSmth(@PathParam("id") String id) {
...
}
...
@GET
@Path(ID_RES)
public Object getSmth(@PathParam("id") String id) {
...
}
```

The can also read [full description](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html#value()) of `Path#value` parameter

## Solution 2

Create and register at your REST server `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter` implementation with `filter` method having needed URI checks.

The single filter parameter has `ContainerRequestContext` type from witch you can call `getUriInfo` for getting URI and method `abortWith(Response response)` which can be used for aborting caller request if your resource ids validation was failed.

See [Chapter 10. Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) chapter of Jersey Manual.

Comment: I have looked into using regexes to solve my issue. The downside I see is that I have to put all my checking logic into a single regex, which makes it harder to maintain if additional constraints come up. Additionally I would like to make a distinction between `ID not found`, and `ID semantically incorrect`.

Comment: The filter approach could work. But as I understand this would mean I have to put my endpoint path structure in two places? The filter has to know the context of the path, as well as the annotated functions themselves. Or can I just somehow refer to the @PathParam variables from within the filter? Seems like using exceptions is the most suited as to not duplicate the logic. Thanks for providing insight into the alternatives!